# Unity: How to move a player using Character controller in step?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to move my Player in "block" of 0.1 unity unit (or 1).

How to modify / configure Character controller to move with "fixed" step?

Comment: Imagine you have a chess board -> Do you want your Character to jump from Field A0 -> A1 (eg. 1 Unit) in 1 Frame? Or do you want to create a method, that makes your Character walk 1Unit in x Frames depending on it's movement Speed? What i really want to say - can you by any chance try to clarify what exactly you want to achieve? :)

Comment: Tobias you're right. What I'm asking is that my character move X unit (1 unit for instance) each second when i press the "move" key (or joypad move control) ... So my character can move only at position x,y,z (1,0,0) or (2,0,0) or (3,0,0) .. not 0.4,0,0 ...

Comment: Do you care about collisions with other objects? My finail question to clarify, Do you only accept answers that make use of the Character Controller?

Comment: I'm actually using Character Controller. If I have to change approach, i don't know if it will be simpler...

Answer (score 3):

### You can use transform.Translate to move the character

```
    //moves the character 1 unit in x direction
    transform.Translate(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the `Character Controller` component to move your object, you would want to use its dedicated methods:

1. [Move](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html)
2. [SimpleMove](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.SimpleMove.html)

Also, there's some difference between the 2 methods stated above.
The `Move` method is more complex and performance wise. As it takes care of complex physics such as gravity, collisions and will move the object by motion.
The `SimpleMove` method, instead, is more lightweight because it will only move the object without taking care of environmental physics.

If you want to move by a single unit, probably the code should look something like this:

```
//Controller being your character controller component
Controller.SimpleMove(Vector3.forward);
```